# Binding presence plugin exchange to another exchange produces no messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.5.1 with the *rabbit_presence_exchange* (binary distribution) and *rabbitmq_event_exchange* (to help debug this issue) plugins and the Python Pika client.

The presence plugin works by giving you a new exchange type: *x-presence*. Binding a queue to this with a routing key generates presence notifications when the queue is bound and unbound (where the routing key is the username for example). Binding a queue without a routing key signs you up to receive presence notifications.

This is fine, I can successfully generate and receive presence notifications like this. However, now I'd like to route the presence messages through an exchange. Initially, I tried to use a header exchange but I wasn't seeing any message coming though, so I changed to a fanout exchange (in case I'd set up the header matching incorrectly) but I'm still not seeing anything coming through.

This is my script to generate and receive presence messages without the additional exchange (i.e. this is the one that works):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pika
import names

MY_NAME = names.get_first_name()
PRESENCE_EXCHANGE = 'presence'

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=PRESENCE_EXCHANGE,
                         exchange_type='x-presence')

result = channel.queue_declare('', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

print('My name is %s and my queue is %r' % (MY_NAME, queue_name))

channel.queue_bind(exchange=PRESENCE_EXCHANGE,
                   queue=queue_name,
                   routing_key=MY_NAME)

channel.queue_bind(exchange=PRESENCE_EXCHANGE,
                   queue=queue_name,
                   routing_key='')


def on_message(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(method, '\n', properties, '\n', body)
    exchange = method.exchange
    if exchange == PRESENCE_EXCHANGE:
        action = properties.headers['action']
        who = properties.headers['key']
        if action == 'bind':
            print(' [+] %s has come online.' % (who,))
        elif action == 'unbind':
            print(' [-] %s has gone offline.' % (who,))


channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name,
                      on_message_callback=on_message,
                      auto_ack=True)


print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
try:
    channel.start_consuming()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    connection.close()
```

I modified the above to route the presence messages to a built-in fanout exchange and binding my queue to that:

```
...
print('My name is %s and my queue is %r' % (MY_NAME, queue_name))

channel.queue_bind(exchange=PRESENCE_EXCHANGE,
                   queue=queue_name,
                   routing_key=MY_NAME)

channel.exchange_bind(source=PRESENCE_EXCHANGE,
                      destination='amq.fanout',
                      routing_key='')

channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.fanout',
                   queue=queue_name)


def on_message(ch, method, properties, body):
...
```

I'm stumped as to why the exchange isn't receiving the messages. Erlang isn't one of my languages so I'm having trouble trying to read the presence plugin's source to determine if this is supported (though I can't see why it wouldn't be).

If anyone has any ideas (or a better way to handle presence with RabbitMQ) I'd love to hear it.

**EDIT:**
With this code and two clients running, my exchanges and bindings look like this:

```
Listing exchanges ...
    direct
amq.direct  direct
amq.fanout  fanout
amq.headers headers
amq.match   headers
amq.rabbitmq.event  topic
amq.rabbitmq.log    topic
amq.rabbitmq.trace  topic
amq.topic   topic
presence    x-presence

Listing bindings ...
    exchange    amq.gen-6aU7qS-ikR4cLmxcT6VKDQ  queue   amq.gen-6aU7qS-ikR4cLmxcT6VKDQ  []
    exchange    amq.gen-MiyEpW9VIxD49PE9SqATFA  queue   amq.gen-MiyEpW9VIxD49PE9SqATFA  []
amq.fanout  exchange    amq.gen-6aU7qS-ikR4cLmxcT6VKDQ  queue   amq.gen-6aU7qS-ikR4cLmxcT6VKDQ  []
amq.fanout  exchange    amq.gen-MiyEpW9VIxD49PE9SqATFA  queue   amq.gen-MiyEpW9VIxD49PE9SqATFA  []
presence    exchange    amq.fanout  exchange        []
presence    exchange    amq.gen-6aU7qS-ikR4cLmxcT6VKDQ  queue   Sheila  []
presence    exchange    amq.gen-MiyEpW9VIxD49PE9SqATFA  queue   Joaquin []
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question to the rabbitmq-users mailing list and got this response:

The plugin implicitly assumes that it works with regular (queue-to-exchange) bindings [3].

RabbitMQ 3.5.x has been out of support for at least a couple of years. Please upgrade [1][2].

1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/upgrade.html
2. https://www.rabbitmq.com/changelog.html
3. https://github.com/rabbitmq/presence-exchange/blob/master/src/presence_exchange.erl#L72